# UIControlEventTouchDown for selected button works incorrect

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, ibaction

I have simple `UIButton` with two states. I added an action to the `button` for `UIControlEventTouchDown` event.  When `button` is in normal state all works great, method is called when I touch the `button`. But when `button` is in `selected state` nothing happens when I touch `button`, only when I release finger, the state changes to normal (Like `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`).

How can I solve this?

I create my button using this method:

```
- (UIButton *) createButtonWithFrame:(CGRect)frame title:(NSString *)title {
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setFrame:frame];
    [button setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitleColor:UIColorFromRGB(0x3a3a3a) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [[button titleLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Gotham-Bold" size:10]];
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_pressed.png"] forState:(UIControlStateSelected)];
    [button setAdjustsImageWhenHighlighted:NO];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    return button;
}
```

And `buttonPressed:` is like this:

```
- (void) buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    [sender setSelected:!sender.selected];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

remove this line fron your code

```
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_pressed.png"] forState:(UIControlStateSelected)];
```

and do like this,

```
- (void) buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {

    if([[sender backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateNormal] isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"]])
        [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_pressed.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    else
        [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: you add
btn=(UIbutton*)sender;